# How to create an extension for Internet Explorer as Exe Com server?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, com, atl, bho

I need to create an extension for Internet Explorer and I need it to be EXE Com server.
First, I created a simple COM DLL project using ATL wizard as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and it worked very well, IE loaded my extension and it showed my message boxes. Next, I repeated all these steps but created COM EXE project. I registered it the same way and Internet Explorer can see the extension but it does not work. My functions IObjectWithSite::SetSite and IObjectWithSite::GetSite aren't called. Could you please advice me how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Your setup is indistinguishable from a virus that infected the machine.  You cannot convince IE to start talking to an out-of-process server, it doesn't have any way to sandbox it.  A BHO must be in-process, rock-hard requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can not register Out-of-Process COM server as a BHO, but you can call COM server from your BHO. E.g. you can use late binding:

```c++
CComDispatchDriver pServer;
if (SUCCEEDED(pServer.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_YourComServer)) {
    pServer.Invoke0(L"ServerMethodName");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have build and register proxy-stub dll for your project (auto generated project with YourServerPS.dll name).